# remove specific elements from numpy array [PREVIOUSLY] selecting elements by data type from a numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

<del>I want to retain only `str` data type and leaving away all other data types such as `int` `float` and `NaN` from a numpy array.</del>

From a numpy array, I wanted to remove certain artifact elements, such as `#NAME?` and `nan`. I get this numpy array from an external program, so I have little or no chance other than re-writing the whole external program myself.

The numpy array I receive from the program looks like the following, when printed to the console:

```
['st' 'ts' 'rs' nan '#NAME?' '0'];
```

From this, I want to remove `nan`, `#NAME?` and `0`. I thought before that these are not of string type, however, after they have correctly been pointed out as of string type from our SO member, I realized they're of string type.

Now I want to remove `nan`, `#NAME?` and `0` from the array. The length of the array varies for each run and the indexes of these elements also varies. How to do that?

I appreciate all your efforts. Many thanks.

<del>While I understand it is not optimal to use mixed data types in numpy arrays, I am restricted to this condition as I receive output from a program as `numpy.ndarray`.</del>

<del>Have explored `numpy.select`. However, it looks like I can only go by values and not data types. Inline pruning would be much better. Any help?</del>

<del>**Edit:**
Apologies for an illframed question. I wanted to remove the `0` and `#NAME?` from the numpy array. I appreciated the efforts. Thanks guys.</del>

Comment: Why? `'#NAME?', '0'` are perfectly valid strings. What are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: A couple of things. First, you have there just standard python lists. Second, `'#NAME?'` and `'0'` are of type `str`. Third, you don't need the `;` at the end of the lines. Fourth, that `nan` like you wrote will give an error since it's a variable name inside the list.

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel Thank you. I have mistakenly presented it as python list. They're numpy.ndarray indeed. Yes, I realize the elements I wanted to remove are 'str' type indeed. Terminal semicolons are of my practice and they're completely legitimate, as far as my understanding with python goes. The 'nan' has been represented as appeared when printed. I have edited to make it look correct now. Once again thank you for your kind efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) takes an *arbitrary* condition list. You could use the condition `isinstance(x, str)` to check if `x` is of type `str`